# SignalR: Sending messages using IHubContext not working, works with Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am playing around with signalR. First it worked fine, but when I moved the code where I call the client to another class (using IHubContext) no message is triggered at the client anymore.

For example I made a simple hub:

```
public class EventHub : Hub
{
    public EventHub()
    {
        Do();
    }

    private async Task Do()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            await Clients.All.foo2("BAR2");
        }
    }
}
```

But I try the same in another class it is not working anymore.

```
public class EventHubTester
{
    private readonly Lazy<IHubContext> context = new Lazy<IHubContext>(() => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventHub>());

    public EventHubTester()
    {
        Do();
    }

    private async Task Do()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            await context.Value.Clients.All.foo("BAR");
        }
    }
}
```

I see in the browser log, that foo2 is triggered, foo is not. Any ideas? I am using signalR 2.2.

Regards,
Sebastian

---

EDIT:

I found the problem. I made a very small example and tested both codes from the post. Then I recognized that it is working fine. So I removed all code from my application step by step until I found the solution:

I use unity for dependency injection and tried two approaches:

1. DOESNT WORK

   ```
   HubConfiguration configuration = new HubConfiguration
   {
       Resolver = new UnitySignalRDependencyResolver(UnityContainer)
   };

   app.MapSignalR(configuration);
   ```
2. WORKS

   ```
   GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new UnitySignalRDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);

   app.MapSignalR(configuration);
   ```

If somebody can explain me the reason, I would be really happy.

Comment: Hub instances are created each time a request is received. How do you create EventHubTester?

Comment: I register it to unitycontainer as singleton and resolve it once. I ensured that the while-loop is iterating during my test.

Comment: Is exception catching turned on? Are you getting any exceptions on either end?

Comment: @Brannon You made me a little bit confused, so I checked it again and added some simple Debug.WriteLine() statements to the asp.net code. There is no excepion and I see foo and foo2 in the output pane. But the client only receives foo2